# Raspberry Pi 3B+ successfully connect and pair but can't receive data from OBD II

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, obd-ii

Hello guys my problem is i cant recieve any data from OBD II to Raspberry Pi 3B+

Here the materials that i use:

Raspberry pi 3B+
ELM327 -> OBD II Bluetooth Adapter
Operating System of Raspberry Pi -> https://medium.com/@aadeshshah/pre-installed-and-pre-configured-raspbian-with-opencv-4-1-0-for-raspberry-pi-3-model-b-b-9c307b9a993a

Here the following step that i do:

> Step 1: From sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.bluez.service i
>   add

```
ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd -C           
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/sdptool add SP
```

> Step 2:Reload the configuration file and Restart the service

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload                            
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth.service
```

> Step 3:Pairing

```
bluetoothctl
```

power on
power on
agent on
default-agent
scan on
scan off 
pair
trust
quit

> Step 4: Stablish connection

```
sudo rfcomm connect rfcomm0
```

Waiting for connection on channel 1 Connection from XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX to /dev/rfcomm0 Press CTRL-C for hangup

It connect but when i run screen /dev/rfcomm0 it can't recieve any data and also when i use cat /dev/rfcomm0 no data posted

This are the tutorial that i use https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DABytIdutKk i change bind to connect command and its work but when i run screen /dev/rfcomm0 i cant get any data

I use the command atz but its just hang up

Comment: Hi. You might be better off asking your question on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: @DavidBuck Ok, thank you